# Access the presenting view controller from the presented view controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have a view controller (containing my menu) presented on top of another view controller (my application).

I would need to access the presenting view controller (below my menu) from the presented view controller (my menu), for example to access some variables or make the presenting view controller perform one of its segues.

However, I just can't figure out how to do it. 
I'm aware of the "presentingViewController" and "presentedViewController" variables but I didn't manage to use them successfully.

Any Idea ?

Code (from the presented VC, which as a reference to the AppDelegate in which the window is referenced) :

```
if let presentingViewController = self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentingViewController {
    presentingViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nameOfMySegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: A common used pattern to solve this issue is to use the delegate design pattern. Declare a delegate in your Menu VC and set the first VC as the delegate. Now you can set a property or a call a method on the delegate. Another way could be to use the notification pattern.

Comment: @TheAppMentor describes two better design patterns over directly referencing the presented view controller.  However, Apple does provide the `presentingViewController` if you want a strongly coupled relationship.

Comment: Both methods actually work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a use of the delegation Design pattern to talk back to the presenting view controller.

First Declare a protocol, that list out all the variables and methods a delegate is expected to respond to.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

    var someVariable : String {get set}

    func doSomething()
}
```

Next : Make your presenting view controller conform to the protocol.
Set your presenting VC as the delegate

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, SomeProtocol {

    var someVariable: String = ""

    func doSomething() {
        // Implementation of do
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Your code goes here.

        if let destVC = segue.destination as? SubVC{
            destVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, when you are ready to call a method on the presenting VC (Delegate).

```
class SubVC: UIViewController {
    var delegate : SomeProtocol?


    func whenSomeEventHappens() {

        // For eg : When a menu item is selected

        // Set some Variable
        delegate?.someVariable = "Some Value"

        // Call a method on the deleate
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice and simple explanation of protocol pattern. Cheers.

Comment: Concise explanation of a topic I've just started to understand properly. Bookmarked this page for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that VCApplication is presenting VCMenu, in VCMenu you can access VCApplication with:

```
weak let vcApplication = self.presentingViewController as? VCApplicationType
```

Your example `self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentingViewController` is looking for the ViewController that presented the `rootViewController` - it will be `nil`.

**EDIT**
Per [TheAppMentor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3765261/theappmentor) I've added `weak` so there are no retain cycles.

Comment: Although this method would work, this will lead to a strong reference cycle. This is because, you now have a your presenting VC referring to Menu VC and Menu VC in turn holding a reference to your Presenting VC.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. 

It appears that you cannot perform a segue on the presenting vc while the presented vc is not dismissed yet. 

You have to dismiss the presented view first, and then call the segue. 

I ended up with :

           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController as? PresentingVCType
            {
                presentingVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nameOfMySegue", sender: self)
            }

Comment: This doesn't account for UITabViewControllers nor UINavigationControllers.