# How to call from a Popover a method of the main view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, popover

In a iOS project, I have a main ViewController and a second ViewController, the second ViewController is displayed as a Popover with a segue from a button in the navigationbar. In that popover there is a button with this code:

```
class Pop: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func colorOnePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = ViewController()
        vc. zoomIn()
    }

}
```

This is the method of the first view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainTextField: UITextView!
    ...

    func zoomIn() {
        mainTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: CGFloat(18.00))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately (and obviously for many of you) I get a fatal error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the method from the new instance of your ViewController. Instead, you need to declare a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW29) property in the Popover VC and pass the original parent VC within [`prepareForSegue:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue) method as a delegate for your Popover VC.

Answer (score 2):

By following the answer to this question by [Aleksandr Medvedev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596869/2480458) and this answer by [TheAppMentor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475264/2480458) to another question, I implemented this by using the delegation design pattern. I post below the code if it can be useful to someone.

Note: I usually see that you use the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate protocol, but I've created a custom one (ZoomProtocol), so I could include my method (zoomOut()).

**In the main view controller:**

```
import UIKit

// declare a protocol, that lists variables and methods
// the delegate is expected to respond to
protocol ZoomProtocol {
    func zoomOut()
}

// set this view controller as the delegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, ZoomProtocol { 

    ...

    // make your presenting view controller conform to the protocol
    zoomOut() {
        // do something
    }

    // pass the this view controller as a delegate for the Popover view controller
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
        if let pop = segue.destination as? PopViewController {
            pop.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

**In the popover view controller:**

```
import UIKit

class PopViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : ZoomProtocol?

    ...

    // when you want to, call the method on the presenting view controller
    @IBAction func zoomOutButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.zoomOut()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the parent View Controller, override prepare to set up the popover:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourPopoverIdentifier" {
        let popoverVC = segue.destination
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popoverVC.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Then in the child's view controller, you can simply call presentingViewController to get access to the parent's functions. In this case the parent is the default View Controller, ViewController.

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let parentVC = self.presentingViewController as! ViewController
    parentVC.functionOnParent()
}
```